# Font-Family Change on Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

After adding Angular Material to my project to utilize Mat-Dialog, I noticed that the font on my website has changed unexpectedly. I would like to know if there is a way to customize the font within the Angular Material Theme or prevent it from altering the font. It's important to note that I am using CSS for styling, not SCSS. Please advise on how to address this font change issue.

I've tried several solutions to override the font in Angular Material using CSS, but unfortunately, none of them have worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Angular Material is overriding what you're trying to do in CSS.

One solution might be to use `define-typography-level` to define a "custom typography level":

> https://material.angular.io/guide/typography
>
> ```
> @use '@angular/material' as mat;
>
> $my-custom-level: mat.define-typography-level(
>   $font-family: Roboto,
>   $font-weight: 400,
>   $font-size: 1rem,
>   $line-height: 1,
>   $letter-spacing: normal,
> );
> ```

Please review the link above.  And - for better or worse - you're probably going to need to use some SASS...